# how to fix json schema to accept json only if required is there?

Tags: arrays, json, object, schema

I am setting JSON schema and when I test it I found it accept anything in list_of_item, please did I miss anything ??

```
{
 "type": "object",
  "storeNumber": {
    "type": "number"
  },
  "inventory_ordering_date": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "date-time"
  },
  "list_of_item": {
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "item_code": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "quantity": {
          "type": "number",
        },
        "unit": {
          "type": "string",
        },
        "required": [
          "item_code",
          "quantity",
          "unit"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "storeNumber",
    "inventory_ordering_date",
    "list_of_item"
  ]
}
```

I want it to reject if there is missing value in list_of_item it should accept only item with item_code, quantity, and unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it, I should set the properties of the object first, then complete the rest

here is the code after editing.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "storeNumber": {
      "type": "integer",
    },
    "inventory_ordering_date": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    },
    "list_of_item": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "item_code": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "quantity": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "unit": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "item_code",
          "quantity",
          "unit"
        ],
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "storeNumber",
    "inventory_ordering_date",
    "list_of_item"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```